# Regex isolate specific string between double quotes

Tags: regex

I have this string:

*"TEST_START" List of 4 $ test : Named num 0.983 ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "W" $ p.value : num 0.975 $ method : chr "**This is the test name**" $ data.name: chr "x" - attr(*, "class")= chr "htest" [1]*

I'm trying to write a regex that could isolate just the following substring withing double quotes: *This is the test name*

At the moment I made this regex:

```
method\s:\schr\s"([^"]*)"
```

It isolates a subset of the string. However I'd need to match just the aforementioned substring (*This is the test name*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
(?<=method\s:\schr\s").*?(?=")
```

See **[Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Width Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**.

RegexBuddy Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`chr "(.*?)" \$` , then pick the second match. Works if you can be confident about how consistent the input string is. But be aware that not all implementations of regex are 100% identical. You might want to be clear about what language you are regex-ing in.